# R getopt package in Rscript on linux cluster returning an error

Tags: r, linux, getopt, rscript

Ive been shared a Rscript to run on a linux cluster, something Ive never done before (and now due to covid restrictions have nobody I can debug it with). The script starts with the R getopt package with what appears to be an if option below the matrix:

```
library("getopt")
    optspec <- matrix(c(
        'reads',     'r', 1, 'character', '/path/to/fastq/reads/',
        'out_dir',   'o', 1, 'character', 'Path to output directory',
        'aggregate', 'a', 0, 'logical',   'Produce aggregated plots',
        'help',      'h', 0, 'logical',   'Display help'
     ),byrow=TRUE,ncol=5)

    opt <- getopt(optspec)

    if (!is.null(opt$help)) {
        cat(getopt(optspec,usage=TRUE))
        q(status=1)
    }

    if (is.null(opt$reads)) {
        cat("Error: no reads argument provconda ided\n")
        cat(getopt(optspec,usage=TRUE))
       q(status=1)
    }

    if (is.null(opt$out_dir)) {
        cat("Error: no out_dir argument provided\n")
        cat(getopt(optspec,usage=TRUE))
        q(status=1)
    }

    aggregate=FALSE

    if (!is.null(opt$aggregate)) {
        aggregate=TRUE
    }
```

The error I get returned on in the output file generate by the cluster is always:

Error: no reads argument provconda ided

Which is why Ive been focussing on the line of code

```
'reads',     'r', 1, 'character', '/path/to/fastq/reads/',
```

I have tried editing the path to fastq files (the script initially said 'reads',     'r', 1, 'character', 'Path to input directory') in various ways Ive seen file paths shown in both R and linux (quotation marks, no / at beginning, replacing path with . etc) but still get the same error so I am now stuck as to what is causing it. Im sure its something very easy Im missing/ not understanding but I cant spot where Im going wrong.

The script starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

#$ -j y
#$ -cwd
```

and is qsubbed from my cwd which is where the fastq files I need to analyse are. I am running in a dada2 environment on the cluster as this is part of a sequence analysis protocol.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you sure the place in the code above is where the location of your data gets set - what did you type in on the command line to run the script (or if it is run from another script what does the line that calls it say?).

Comment: I beilive the get opt package is used to pass arguments in R - there is a pdf manual of it here:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getopt/index.html

Comment: If you look on page 2 you can see that that matrix on linrd 3 to 6 is defining the options that need to be passed onto the script (I'm guesing by either -r your_dir or --reads your_dir )

Comment: @SRD, the qsub command line to run the script included both -cwd and -V options and I have tried running the script from the directory and the directory above where the fastq files are. I have also tried qsub without specifying the cwd. This the first step in the script so theres no other place where the location of the files is set.
Im afraid I didnt understand your comment about the manual- I have looked at the manual whilst trying to troubleshoot and still cant see whats missing/ not right in my code- would you be able to expand your response please? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Try using a -r /location_I_ave_files or -cmd  r  /location/I/have/files

Comment: It looks to me the code you have shown is where the script defines what options it accepts/needs.  The first two entries on each line are the long and short forms of the option name (reads or r), the 1 after the 'r' means this options the option requires one argument and it will be taken to by of type charactor and the last entry on each line is the help message.

Comment: I should add I'm not an expert in R but in python if you type "python my_script.py --option1 foobar " then within the script the value foobar can be accessed as option1.  (Sorry if this is just a guess) but if adding -r file/location to the end of the command that runs the script try changing that "#$ -cmd" to "#$ -cmd r /file/location"

Comment: This is not quite the right package but : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GetoptLong/vignettes/GetoptLong.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, so where I went wrong is editing the matrix:
    'reads',     'r', 1, 'character', '/path/to/fastq/reads/',
should have been left as:
     'reads',     'r', 1, 'character', 'path to input directory'
and I needed to add the actual path to the directory on the qsub command line by passing an -r option (which may have been what you suggested above but I didnt understand!). Likewise Ive also discovered I need an -o option on the qsub command line too

Comment: Glad to help : I'll type a more complete response below so others can see the solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not where the options the script needs gets set.  The arguments need to get passed in from the command line.

Instead of running the script using `my_script_name` you need to use `my_script_name -r /path/to/fastq/reads` or `my_scrip_name --reads /path/to/fastq/reads`
The code you show is where the script learns what options to accept and which ones must be set.  Do not edit these.

As an example in

> 'reads',     'r', 1, 'character', '/path/to/fastq/reads/'

the first two entries are the long and short forms of the option name (reads or r), the 1 after the 'r' means this option requires one argument of type charactor after it and the last entry on each line is the help message.

The if statements in the above code mean that if you do not give -r (or --reads) and -o (or --out_dir), the script will print the help message (which you can also get by calling the script with -h as an option).  The q(status=1) is what causes the script to return without doing anything.

-a (or --aggragate) is optional and defaults to FALSE . If you give this option to the script by adding '-a' at the end of the command line then it will change the plot style in some way the code you have shown does not show.